# unity gradle build failed could not resolve launcher:classpath

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle

When i want to build project in unity 2020.2.7 I see some error in building gradle as shown here:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.0/gradle-3.6.0.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.6.0/builder-3.6
```

I tick the custom build gradle template in player Setting and changed the
classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.4` as I use the unity 2020.2.7 but it doesn't solve the problem.

Added the JAVA_HOME in Environment variable and I use jdk 1.8.291. Can anyone help me?

Comment: after i added custom build gradle the 3.6.0 changed to 5.6.4 but nothing has changed and bug remained.

Comment: In Unity 2020, you can make a build by checking the AndroidManifest only. Keep everything else unchecked.

Comment: In some cases i even dont need manifest file and without it i made apk...